# How to convert from hex-encoded string to a "human readable" string?

Tags: python-2.7, hex, net-snmp

I'm using the Net-SNMP bindings for python and I'm attempting to grab an ARP cache from a Brocade switch. Here's what my code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import netsnmp

def get_arp():
    oid = netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('ipNetToMediaPhysAddress'))
    res = netsnmp.snmpwalk(oid, Version=2, DestHost='10.0.1.243', Community='public')
    return res

arp_table = get_arp()

print arp_table
```

The SNMP code itself is working fine. Output from `snmpwalk` looks like this:

```
<snip>
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.128.10.200.6.158 = STRING: 0:1b:ed:a3:ec:c1
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.129.10.200.6.162 = STRING: 0:1b:ed:a4:ac:c1
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.130.10.200.6.166 = STRING: 0:1b:ed:38:24:1
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.131.10.200.6.170 = STRING: 74:8e:f8:62:84:1
</snip>
```

But my output from the python script yields a tuple of hex-encoded strings that looks like this:

```
('\x00$8C\x98\xc1', '\x00\x1b\xed;_A', '\x00\x1b\xed\xb4\x8f\x81', '\x00$86\x15\x81', '\x00$8C\x98\x81', '\x00\x1b\xed\x9f\xadA', ...etc)
```

I've spent some time googling and came across the `struct` module and the `.decode("hex")` string method, but the `.decode("hex")` method doesn't seem to work:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hexstring = '\x00$8C\x98\xc1'
>>> newstring = hexstring.decode("hex")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found
>>>
```

And the documentation for `struct` is a bit over my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more clever google-fu uncovered this code snippet, which gives me the results I expect:

```
def convertMac(octet):
    mac = [binascii.b2a_hex(x) for x in list(octet)]
    return ":".join(mac)
```

So "decoding" is really a misnomer, because this code also yields a proper result (with `encode` and `decode` appearing to be syntactic sugar for `binascii.a2b()` and `binascii.b2a()`):

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> string = '\x00$8\xa1\x1c2'
>>> string.encode("hex")
'002438a11c32'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `"hex"` to `"hex_codec"` for Python < 3

This applies to python 3+ Possible to use?

```
>>> codecs.decode(b"4f6c6567", "hex_codec")
b'Oleg'
>>> codecs.getdecoder("hex_codec")(b"4f6c6567")
(b'Oleg', 8)
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for me either - getting the same error as above: `TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found`. I did find a solution however which I'll post shortly